# "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis" setting doesnt work for C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, formatting, editor

Below are my vscode settings

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
"typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true
```

And when I copy paste code, I am expecting it to retain the space after funtion name and before parenthesis. But I am unable to get it working.

CTRL + Z does retain the spaces, but removes indentation. I want the `formatonpaste(editor.formatOnPaste)` to work.

Comment: This space is probably not a good idea in the first place. (IMHO)

Comment: Thankyou @chqrlie, yeah may be I should take it up with vscode community. However this is a common problem I tried to see user experience before taking it to community.